# How to print a Ptython3 from a regex result that expand over 2 lines

Tags: python

I have a small python 3 script that reads a file where all the bookmarks are stored. My regex works in notepad++.

my regex is:

```
(==========)([\r\n]+.*)
```

My text file

```
==========
Book1 (Author 1)
- bookmark

text
==========
Book2 (Author 2)
- bookmark1

text
==========
﻿Book1 (Author 1)
- bookmark2

text
==========
Book2 (Author 2)
- bookmark2

text
==========
```

My Python script is as follows:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(==========)([\r\n])(.*)")
count=0
for line in open(r'bookmarks.txt', encoding="utf-8"):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        count=count+1
        print(line)
print("The amount of notes are: ",count)
```

The problem with this is the printed lines are only showing the "==========" part and excluding the:

```
==========
Book1 (Author 1)
```

I have tried different ways but none of them are showing what i'm looking for, any hint?

Thanks

Comment: What exact output do you want?

Comment: In your example text file, I assume all the entries should be different, i.e., in reality `Book 1` and `Book 2` won't be repeated?

Comment: Do you want the `==========` included in your output?

Comment: In reality `Book 1` and `Book 2` will be repeated several times within the text file, this to differentiate each bookmark from each book. 
With the regex I have i can print out the `==========` but the second part of my regex seems to be ignored in the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching *line by line*, so for lines without the `==========` there's no way to match your pattern. You could try something like the following instead:

```py
with open(r'bookmarks.txt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    bookmarks = file.read()
pattern = re.compile("(==========)(\r\n)([^\n]+)")
count = 0
for match in pattern.finditer(bookmarks):
    count += 1
    print(match[0])
print("The amount of notes are: ", count)
```

Read the whole `bookmarks.txt` file into a string and then start searching. It's not exactly clear what parts of the bookmarks you want to retrieve, so I've limited it to the first line.

Result here:

```
==========
Book1 (Author 1)
==========
Book2 (Author 2)
==========
Book1 (Author 1)
==========
Book2 (Author 2)
The amount of notes are:  4
```

Comment: You're right, trying the searching aproach you suggest does the trick with the regex I initially propose.
`(==========)([\r\n]+.*)`
The REGEX proposed as `(==========)(\r\n)([^\n]+)` doesn't work.

Comment: @hectorlerma I guess the pattern depends a bit on the platform and the exact output you want (did work here, without the `\r`, under Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Your finditer-regex is applied to single lines of the input file only. Therefore, it cannot match the book-lines after "========". Why it finds anything at all? That's because you are allowing empty book-lines (`(.*)`).

It's not clear to me, what output you expect, but the following piece of code at least prints the separator line together with the book-line:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(==========)([\r\n]+)(.+)")
count=0
with open('bookmarks.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    bookmarks = file.read()

for match in re.finditer(pattern, bookmarks):
    count=count+1
    print(match.group(0))
print("The amount of notes are: ",count)
```

Note, that I replaced `(.*)` by `(.+)`.